# Convert Sub to Class for multiple CurrTextBox's

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have been using the following Subs to check and ensure data entered into a TextBox is numeric and it then gets converted to currency decimals in a form with a single CurrTextBox, however I have now been tasked to create a form with multiple CurrTextBox's.

How would I convert the following code to handle multiple calls.  I suppose I can create a Public Sub that the data entered into a particular CurrTextBox calls...  Ideas?

```
Private Sub CurrBox2_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
    If (e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) OrElse (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
        acceptableKey = True
    Else
        acceptableKey = False
    End If
End Sub
' This sub handles the keypress inputs and ensures values are numeric only
Private Sub CurrBox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    ' Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
    If acceptableKey = False Then
        ' Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
        e.Handled = True
        Return
    Else
        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back) Then
            If strCurrency.Length > 0 Then
                strCurrency = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 1)
            End If
        Else
            strCurrency = strCurrency & e.KeyChar
        End If

        If strCurrency.Length = 0 Then
            CurrBox2.Text = ""
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 1 Then
            CurrBox2.Text = "0.0" & strCurrency
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 2 Then
            CurrBox2.Text = "0." & strCurrency
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 2 Then
            CurrBox2.Text = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 2) & "." & strCurrency.Substring(strCurrency.Length - 2)
        End If
        CurrBox2.Select(CurrBox2.Text.Length, 0)

    End If
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask why you're not using the [NUD - NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control?

Comment: Not everyone likes the way they look.

Comment: Why muck around with every single keystroke?  All that really matters is that the data is valid which can be done with one line of code using `Decimal.TryParse` when they submit the form as "done" (ie and OK or Done button).

Comment: I hadn't thought of the NUD before, I'll take a look.  I forgot about Tryparse, mostly because I didn't want them to even have the opportunity to enter anything but numerics, and the value will always be in currency form.

Answer (score 0):

One event can handle multiple controls.

Just add more controls after Handles clause in your events and all of these to be handled.

```
Private Sub CurrBox2_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles currbox1.keydown, currbox2.keydown, currbox3.keydown
    If (e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) OrElse (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
        acceptableKey = True
    Else
        acceptableKey = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This way you need write those events only once.
I hope I was undertand your question right.